# wien bridge input impedance

Tags: transistors

[image]

I want to know the input impedance at transistor T1's base.
1/Z=1/R4+1/R+1/Rin and Rin=beta(re+RE)
But how do I calculate RE ?
My guess : R3 is 0 because the wire at T1 collector is removed, thereby RE=Lp ?
Thanks

Comment: Why not RE||Lp ? For what purpose you need to know Rin?

Comment: You mean re||Lp ?
I need to make sure that the overall gain is 3 (with both transistors)

Comment: Ups I meant R3||LP But isn't it the overall gain set by (1+ R3/LP) and Lp is a RE at DC?

Comment: Don't forget that you need a gain of more than 3. The Lamp (Lp) will vary its resistance with amplitude to control the gain to achieve stable oscillation. Also as shown R2 will affect the DC bias of the transistor. You may need to AC couple to T1 base.

Comment: G36, I think it's correct, because in theory R3 is 2 times bigger than Lp. Thank you

Comment: Kevin White, yes I added a pot to play around the gain. I also added a cap at the bias. Thanks.